# How to set a masked redirect in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, http-redirect

How to set a `redirect` of the ***www***.domain.com (only `route('index')`) to ***web***.domain.com on `www`, which has a Laravel app and `web` holds Wordpress? I have an access to domain configurations.

Comment: This? `return Redirect::to($url);` https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects

Comment: Well, I need a masked redirect. See this (MASKED REDIRECTION), please. https://www.websupport.sk/en/redirect

Comment: do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: One option is creating a view and use an iframe to load the blog inside it.

Comment: @AgnesPalit I already tried most of the `Route` methods with `redirect()`, but none of them redirects with masked url.
@wp78de iframe is not a good solution because of styling and security issues

Comment: what I mean is please show by type your code that you just tried on your question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (masked) [URL frame](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/adding-a-redirect-for-your-website), e.g, if I understand your hierarchy correctly:

```
Route::get('/index',function(){
    return view('blog');
});
```

block.blade.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://web.domain.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

or try a rewrite without redirect on the webserver level. If you are using Apache:

A rewrite without redirect requires enabled mod_proxy, as well as mod_rewrite and .htaccess through Apache's httpd.conf. (Unless it's the same VirtualHost, it cannot be done without mod_proxy, see Absolute URL in the Substitution section in the refs. It "always" forces an external redirect.)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if not already web.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^web\.mydomain\.com$ [NC] 
#rewrite request is for www/* to web.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^index/?$ http://web.mydomain.com/$1 [L,P,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @wp78de. Unfortunatelly I don't have an access to apache settings because of shared hosting. Speaking about iframe, is it a safe solution?

Comment: There are definitely some [downsides of URL masking](https://www.easyredir.com/blog/why-you-should-not-use-url-masking-forwarding-cloaking/) but depending on the nature of your blog, if both sites use HTTPS and you are not passing data between them, I think you are fine.